# How to minimize my navigation bar on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

My navigation bar works great on bigger screens, but once I get to my phone, the "properties"link goes right underneath my navigation bar. How do I fix this? 
Can I minimize the size only for smaller screens? so that it looks exactly the same as it does on the big screen?

Also, I'm very new at this, so I Kindly ask for you to be very specific.
Thank you.

```css
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
  <style type="text/css">
 
    @media (max-width: 600px){
  .responsive{
   width:100% !important;
   padding-left:2% !important;
   padding-right:2% !important;
   text-align:jusitfy !important;
   margin-left:auto !important;
   margin-right:auto !important;
  }

} @media (max-width: 600px){
  .height{
   height:auto !important;
  }

} @media (max-width: 600px){
  .responsive img{
   width:100% !important;
   height:auto !important;
   text-align:center !important;
  }
```

```html
<body bottommargin="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <!-- START SECTION ONE -->
    
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;border-bottom:1px solid #707070;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <table align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:620px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <table align="center" style="width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%" align="right" style="padding:10px;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-size:10px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;">
                            
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsive">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" width="100%" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;line-height:20px;letter-spacing:px;" class="responsive">
                            
                            <!-- your navigation bar below -->
                            
                            <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/about">
                              ABOUT US
                            </a>
                            
                            <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/about#!contact">
                              BROKERS
                            </a>
                            
                            <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/home#!contact">
                              CONTACT
                            </a>
                          
                            <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/properties">
                              PROPERTIES
                            </a>
```

Comment: you need to alter the font-size in your media queries too

Comment: I would recommend not using tables for layout because they are hard to make responsive. If you're just starting out, you can use the `div` element for pretty much anything and it would be better than using `table`, `tr`, and `td`. Table layouts are a very '90s practice. Check out this guide: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/

You seem to have already discovered media queries, which can help define styles for different screen sizes, but most of the time you should be able to make a site responsive without them by using percent and `em` for sizing in CSS.

Comment: makes sense, is it possible for you to show me how to do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to specify a the same media query for each styling you add just one is enough.

one solution to your problem would be decreasing the font-size for smaller screens.

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 2% !important;
    padding-right: 2% !important;
    text-align: jusitfy !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
  }
  .height {
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .responsive img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  * {
    font-size: 10px
  }
}
```

```html
<body bottommargin="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <!-- START SECTION ONE -->

  <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;border-bottom:1px solid #707070;">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
              <table align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:620px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table align="center" style="width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" align="right" style="padding:10px;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-size:10px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsive">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="100%" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;line-height:20px;letter-spacing:px;" class="responsive">

                          <!-- your navigation bar below -->

                          <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/about">
                              ABOUT US
                            </a>

                          <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/about#!contact">
                              BROKERS
                            </a>

                          <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/home#!contact">
                              CONTACT
                            </a>

                          <a style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/properties">
                              PROPERTIES
                            </a>
</body>
```

I just used `*{font-size: 10px}` to target everything for the sake of this explanation, but you'll have to adjust each one as you like.

Hope it Helps :)

Comment: but if I do that, won't the font size on bigger screens also be 10px? (sorry very new at this)

Comment: No we using it under the media Query, it applies the styling we define under that condition. you wanna read a bit about media queries to understand how it works : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp